# Equality achieved with limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

For a function $f(x)$, if we have for any $k\in (0,1)$:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-k\ln(x) \leq 0  $$ 
And 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-\ln(x) \geq 0$$

Are the above two equations enough to justify that:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-\ln(x) = 0$$

My proof is maximizing the first equation by letting $k\to 1$, then we have:
$$\lim_{k\to1}\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-k\ln(x)=  \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-\ln(x)\leq0  $$
Then:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-\ln(x) \leq 0 \leq  \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-\ln(x)$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)-\ln(x) = 0$$

I want to know whether this proof is sound enough?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof is valid. Note that you can see it in this way, too. You have that $\forall\epsilon>0$
  holds$$\log\left(x\right)\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f\left(x\right)\leq\epsilon\log\left(x\right)$$
 then it be necessary holds your equality, for the arbitrariness of $\epsilon.$